# Jquery val() некорректно работает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть input с `dir="rtl"` (перевернутый, ввод справа налево) и такой код:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // input dir="rtl" (мне нужен ввод с права на лево)
  var number = '12345.'; // точка в конце строки
  $('#input').val(number); // а вставляется вначале
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" dir="rtl" maxlength="8" />
```

Точка вставляется в начало строки! Но я ставлю её в конец. Хотя в консоле все правильно - вставляет в конец. Видимо это происходит из-за `dir="rtl"`.

[**Пример**](http://jsbin.com/gijinuceqo/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: а зачем в данном случае нужна точка в конце?

Comment: Это что то похожее на калькулятор

Comment: Удивительно, но `<span dir="rtl">12345.</span>` будет вести себя так же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var number = '12345';
$('#input').val('.' + number);
```